# Texture paint only right in Solid mode, becomes broken in render mode, Anyone know what's wrong?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, texture-painting

[image: This is the render mode]

[image: This is the solid mode]

[image: This is Nodes]

anyone know what is wrong with it? (first picture render mode, second picture solid mode, third picture nodes)

Comment: Maybe it's because you've created 2 UV Map, switch to the other one?

Comment: if moonboots comment doesn't help, please provide blend file

Comment: I don't know how to put the blender file here, but here's the file from google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bmTLD_-TK45F22kD7GYjOPnsVISHh6sY/view?usp=sharing , and also I've have tried using different UV Map but it's still the same.

Comment: Problem solved! I used the wrong nodes it should be flat not box. Thanks guys!